# Is it possible to diable force stop button for a flutter application. If so how?

Tags: android, flutter

My flutter application tracks user location in the background. I need to disable the force stop button so that the application does not stop tracking the user location. Any hint to solve this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: No. You cannot turn off device features like force stopping apps and that's a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a normal `if else` :

```
bool shouldNotStopTracking = true;
// ...
onPressed: shouldNotStopTracking ? null :  actionMethod(),
// ...
```

now when the user clicks on the button nothing will happens because the button `onPressed` is `null` so the button is disabled.